# how to link order source with transactions in oracle apps

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am new to oracle apps .Just wanted some help in a query . I want to know how to link order source with transactions table.

Comment: We don't know what these tables look like. Edit you post to include sample data, expected output, and what you have tried so far. In the mean time, have a look at the [tutorial in the wiki](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In the import program, you have to derive the order type based on the customer classification or based on the item type.

Else, you have have Defaulting Rules do the duty. In this case, the order type/ order_type_id should be left blank.